# Select webcam box lost in Skype after Windows 10 updated to 14393 build

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1607

I cannot change  between built-in and USB camera - only built-in one available in Skype.
Anyone experienced this glitch? I removed Skype Preview and reinstalled Skype - no joy.

Comment: Does the USB camera show in device manager and work with other apps?

Comment: All is working perfectly in Camera application. So it looks like Skype specific issue.